# OpenLayers: How to set up alert() on polygons on click

Tags: vector, click, openlayers, polygon

I tried the last week very hard to fix my problem, but I didn't find an answer. I hope you can help me:
I want to install several polygons (resembling buildings on my campus), using a OpenStreetMap as base layer. When a polygon is clicked with the mouse, I want to produce a specific alert() or other output, which belongs to exactly the clicked polygon (I want to give informations about the clicked building). All examples I found just worked with ONE click event for each polygon, because all polygons were set in one layer. When setting up a layer for each polygon, just the top layer remained clickable. 
With Markers it works perfect, because I can identify every marker, even in the same layer:

```
llm = new OpenLayers.LonLat(Lon2Merc(lonm), Lat2Merc(latm));  
var marker2 = new OpenLayers.Marker(llm, icon);
marker2.events.register("mousedown", marker2, 
      function() { alert("Hello marker 2"); });
layer_markers.addMarker(marker2);
```

with polygons its different...
I hope you can help me,
greets
Philip

Answer (score 1):

Polygons are vector objects (features) and placed on vector layers (OpenLayers.Layer.Vector). The common way to manage clicks on polygons in OpenLayers is using [SelectFeature](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Control/SelectFeature-js.html) control.

You should try this demo (and look into the source code):
http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/select-feature-openpopup.html